# How sync.Cond works?

Tags: go

I'm trying to understand how to works `sync.Cond` but it doesn't work for me.
My code

```
c := sync.NewCond(&sync.Mutex{})

var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)

go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    c.L.Lock()
    defer c.L.Unlock()
    c.Wait()
    fmt.Println("I'm created")
}()

c.Signal()
wg.Wait()
```

I always get the deadlock, but if I remove `defer` before `wg.Done()` nothing appears but I don't get an error in this case. I have seen other examples but they are different. I want to understand the fundamental ideas sync.Cond using my example. I don't know where's an error here because goroutine runs and it's ok then it waits for a signal but in main goroutine I do this c.Signal() and therefore I hope goroutine will resume but It doesn't happen...

Comment: Why are you calling `c.L.Lock` and `c.L.Unlock` here? That's what's causing the deadlock - `c.Signal` can't run because it's locked, and `c.L.Unlock` can't run because it runs after `c.Wait`, which is waiting on the `c.Signal` that can't run.

Comment: Sorry for my fail... But how can I solve it?

Comment: See my previous comment. The quickest path to fix it would be to stop messing with the mutex because it doesn't look like you have any reason to be locking and unlocking it.

Comment: @Adrian, locking L is required: ["Each Cond has an associated Locker L ... which must be held ... when calling the Wait method."](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Cond) I'm pretty sure the deadlock occurs because the main goroutine calls Signal before Wait has a chance to run. Inserting time.Sleep(time.Second) before Signal fixes it: https://play.golang.org/p/JQmR4Cw313w

Comment: `sync.Cond` is about notifying one or all waiters in a group.  I agree with @Peter about why this doesn't work, but even more so, this code doesn't demonstrate the usefullness of `sync.Cond`.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule,<sup>1</sup> when you're using a `sync.Cond` variable, you need *two* things that go with it:

- a mutex, and
- a data structure that the mutex is protecting.

Within that data structure, you need to have some variable that tells you that the condition itself is fulfilled, or is not fulfilled.

This leads to code of this form:

```golang
type whatever struct {
    ready  bool
    done   bool
    input  string
    result string
    lock   sync.Mutex
    cond   *sync.Cond
}

func doStuff(p *whatever) {
    p.lock.Lock()
    defer p.lock.Unlock()
    for !p.ready && !p.done {
        p.cond.Wait()
    }
    fmt.Printf("working on thing with input=%q\n", p.input)
    p.result = "all done now"
    p.done = true
    p.cond.Signal()
}

func waitDone(p *whatever) {
    p.lock.Lock()
    defer p.lock.Unlock()
    for !p.done {
        p.cond.Wait()
    }
}
```

which you then use from elsewhere with, e.g.:

```golang
    var obj whatever
    obj.cond = sync.NewCond(&obj.lock)
    go doStuff(&obj)
    obj.lock.Lock()
    obj.input = "some input"
    obj.ready = true // object is now ready to be worked-on
    obj.lock.Unlock()
    obj.cond.Signal()
    waitDone(&obj)
    fmt.Printf("obj is done, result is %q\n", obj.result)
```

There's a complete example of this [here](https://play.golang.org/p/froQ4NI-4Yq).

Now, *as written*, there's no reason to use a `sync.Cond` here.  A mutex alone would suffice for this case.  We really use a `sync.Cond` when *multiple* concurrent routines need to wait for some event.  For instance, perhaps the object will be needed by multiple goroutines: one should do the work, then it should mark the object as ready and use a *broadcast* to alert everyone who's waiting for that one object.  In this case, `doStuff()` would end with `p.cond.Broadcast()` rather than `p.cond.Signal()`.

In some other cases, we might have an object that gets ping-pong-ed around between various goroutines.  One or more goroutines are, or at least may be, waiting for the object.  One of them—let's call this particular goroutine Fred—gets control of it and does some limited amount of work on the object, then declares that *this* goroutine is done.  Fred puts the object back into a suitable state (with some but not all work done) and invokes `p.cond.Signal()`, which wakes either of two other goroutines that are all waiting for the object.  Whichever one is awakened will take the object, do a little more work on it, and then put it back into a suitable state and invoke `p.cond.Signal()` to signal anyone else waiting.

Eventually, the work is all done and whoever has finished it sets `p.done` and calls `p.cond.Broadcast()` to alert *everyone* who might have a handle on `p` that `p` is now done.

Condition variables are more flexible than a simple mutex, but require a lot more thought and care.  If a simple mutex alone will get the job done, it's usually best to just use the mutex.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are some cases where you can violate this rule, but if you were ready to think about these cases, you wouldn't have had this problem in the first place.